# Run tests in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to make a build pipeline in Azure DevOps including tests/code coverage.

For that, I created a very basic Java project:

```
package main:
    - main class
    - Calculator class
          - add method
package test:
    - CalculatorTest class
        - addTest method
```

It's very basic, just for me to understand how test in pipeline work. I don't use maven or things like that. For the tests, I'm using JUnit framework.

In Azure DevOps pipeline, I imported my project from Github, and started to create the pipeline. I start from the starter template, which contains:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

My question is:

What do I have to do to run my tests automatically ?

I've seen several examples on the Microsoft documentation but it was always for "complex" projects (like with maven etc.). And ass I'm new with Azure DevOps and YAML file/syntax, I'm lost.

I want to run my tests after each commit, and see the results (test + code coverage) in the pipeline summary, like it is described here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#view-test-results-in-build

Thanks a lot.

PS: For the moment I'm just focusing on tests but once it will be done I also would like to publish build artefacts. I would like the confirmation of that:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

Is that line correct ?

**EDIT**

The line `- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1` seems to work correclty but I have the following warning:

```
Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the visual designer (like explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/iot-edge/how-to-ci-cd) and I added the Maven task.

I upgraded my project to use Maven, which is well integrated in Azure Devops.